# How android app can be generated through website?

Tags: php, android, apk

I'm just curious about how these websites now a days can create an android apk? i mean what logic is behind it? is it possible that you can compile a code in PHP or is there something else?

e.g. for websites that can generate android apps

http://www.appsgeyser.com/

http://ibuildapp.com/

So just as a student, its killing me to know what they do for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowerdays with the gradle build system that is not too hard. You just need to execute on the commandline `gradlew aR` and some minutes later you have a brand new apk file.

```
shell_exec('./gradlew aR');
```

That should do it's job but keep in mind that this can take some minutes.

A better way would be to queue that job in a database and execute the creation with a cronjob. That would be more secure.

Answer (score 1):

They invoke the Android build tools on automatically generated code to produce the APK.

In fact, they do exactly what you would do to produce an APK, except that some of the code and resources are pre-built (and the same for every application), and whereas you would use Eclipse or Android Studio to compile the code, they are using scripts to so the same thing that the IDE would do.

Comment: but what is the way for invoking those tools automatically?

Comment: @user1602152 the PHP scripts will be executing them as external programs. They are all command line applications.

Comment: oh so according to you, i should create a template project through eclipse or whatever IDE, then add some code which i generate from user's inputs and then build the apk through PHP scripts?

Comment: @awaistoor If you want to create an Android app automatically via a web site, you mean? Yes. You'd want to write it in such a way that as little as possible varies according to user input; get the script to replace a file or two from your project; and then get it to invoke the command-line build tools to compile the APK. As rekire says, the gradle build system might be the easiest.